# Google Authenticator for iOS Missing Files

Tags: ios, google-authenticator

I have cloned the Google Authenticator source code from [here](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator). After opening the iOS project in Xcode, I realized that a lot of files are missing, thus resulting in hundreds of compilation errors when I try to build. Just a few of the missing files are:

```
GTMNSDictionary+URLArguments.h
GTMNSString+URLArguments.h
GTMLocalizedString.h
GTMRegex.h
```

Has anyone been able to build the iOS project for Google Authenticator?

**UPDATE (June 29, 2015)**

I was able to find the missing ZXing files [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/00f634024ceeee591f54e6984ea7dd666fab22ae/iphone) and the missing Google Toolbox for Mac files [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/checkout). Then, I ran into a build error in `OTPAuthURLEntryController.m` at this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) __attribute__((NSObject)) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

I fixed it by changing the line to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

Now I'm trying to fix the following "symbol(s) not found" issue:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Decoder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OTPAuthURLEntryController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've searched all over SO but still haven't figured it out yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the missing ZXing files [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/00f634024ceeee591f54e6984ea7dd666fab22ae/iphone) and the missing Google Toolbox for Mac files [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/checkout). I then added the appropriate missing files to the project. After this, I ran into a build error in `OTPAuthURLEntryController.m` at this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) __attribute__((NSObject)) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

I fixed it by changing the line to:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

After that, I ran into the following "symbol(s) not found" error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Decoder", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in OTPAuthURLEntryController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It turns out that the main project (`OTPAuth`) is linking to a library called `libZXingWidget.a`, which is missing (like many other things). I opened up the `ZXingWidget` project in the missing ZXing files and fixed the build errors by removing the custom flags that treated warnings as errors. Then, I built the static library and set the build target to **iOS Device**. This generated the `libZXingWidget.a` file I needed. I linked that file in the Build Phases of the main project (`OTPAuth`), and now Google Authenticator runs on the iPhone 6 simulator!